# Addthis like button doesn't work, but stop and refresh every time

Tags: button, facebook-like, addthis

i have installed the Addthis share buttons with FB like button + count.
when i click on like the script load but only for 1or2 seconds, then it destroy and everything is as before i've clicked.

it's a conflict or a known issue?? thanks.

Comment: got an url, markup? seems weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is any help but here's what I did:

- get the addthis code with facebook button
- get the facebook button code from facebook
- copy the facebook code and use this to replace the button code in the addthis code

works for me